# Trimming systemd components in containers

Tags: systemd, system-installation, container

I am working with container on a systemd platform.  While I create a container using lxc commands, I see that all the systemd components are present inside this container as well.  I am planning to trim down most of these components as I don't need many of these.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First I would work on focusing the problem you are trying to solve. When you say "components", are you concerned about the disk space, memory use or CPU of these services? For each one, have you measured to see much impact they actually take?

If the components you refer to are systemd services, then you use standard systemd management commands to disable them:

```
`systemctl disable my-service-name`.
```